# Installing Xray and configure with Jfrog Artifactory using Docker compose

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-xray

We were trying to Integrate Xray with our Jfrog Artifactory. In Amazon Linux 2 we are trying to install with docker compose,while we run the config.sh

[image]

After running the bellow docker compose commands

```
start rabbitmq:   docker-compose -p xray-rabbitmq -f docker-compose-rabbitmq.yaml up -d

start postgresql:  docker-compose -p xray-postgres -f docker-compose-postgres.yaml up -d

start: docker-compose -p xray up -d
```

xray router is getting restarting after 20sec with following error:

[image]

We have checked whether any selinux, firewalld, or iptables are blocking,but all are in disable state.

Can someone help us to resolve the issue?

---

Now Private IP is able to reach Artifactory server,we have created Xray in same VPC of Artifactory.
Now all containers of Xray are running in Xray server,but now we have a different issue.
In xray server container we are getting  the below logs

```
2021-08-12T13:41:17.601Z [jfxr ] [INFO ] [469946e5f04dd2c6] [updates_service:486           ] [main                ] Initializing JFrog vendor
2021-08-12T13:41:17.700Z [jfxr ] [ERROR] [                ] [bin_mgr_cache:50              ] [main                ] Failed to get binary managerid:failed on GetAllBinaryManagerIds query
 --- at /go/src/jfrog.com/xray/internal/dbaccess/dao/binary_managers_dao.go:367 (binMgrDao.GetBinaryManagerId) ---
Caused by: not found
2021-08-12T13:41:17.701Z [jfxr ] [ERROR] [                ] [bin_mgr_cache:59              ] [main                ] Failed to get binary manager'' version, err :failed to fetch binary manager
 --- at /go/src/jfrog.com/xray/internal/dbaccess/dao/binary_managers_dao.go:290 (binMgrDao.GetBinMgrByID) ---
Caused by: not found
2021-08-12T13:41:17.701Z [jfxr ] [WARN ] [                ] [indexed_resources_cache:36    ] [main                ] Failed to get binary managerfor cache:failed to fetch binary manager
 --- at /go/src/jfrog.com/xray/internal/dbaccess/dao/binary_managers_dao.go:290 (binMgrDao.GetBinMgrByID) ---
Caused by: not found
```

Any idea on this?

Comment: what value did you give for JFrogURL?

Comment: I have provided the URL with Private IP ( http://priavteIP:portnumber)

But in Admin > Security > Settings > ( its with https://FQDN)

Actually from Xray server,we are unable to access the JFrogURL with https:\\FQDN thats y I have provided the Private IP

Answer (score 0):

@praseeb It appears you are giving JFrogURL as the node IP of xray. It should be the reachable URL of artifactory from the xray machine, Please pick it from `Admin > Security > Settings` as indicated.

Comment: I have provided the URL with Private IP ( http://priavteIP:portnumber)

But in Admin > Security > Settings > ( its with https://FQDN)

Actually from Xray server,we are unable to access the JFrogURL with https:\\FQDN thats y I have provided the Private IP

Comment: The private IP should be reachable from Xray to Artifactory and also from Artifactory to Xray. What is the shared.node.ip given? Is that IP reachable by Artifactory?

Comment: shared.node.ip is Xray IP.

New update of this issue has been updated in the summary with Error.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with some custom Docker Compose files.

It was a network issue, the containers (server, indexer, analysis, persist) did not start in the same network as the router. This occurs because I use `docker-compose [...] --no-start`.

With the `--no-start` option, the `network_mode: service:router` was ignored and the containers goes to the default bridge network. So they cannot communicate with the router on local ports (8046, etc).